# Does NeoVim really need plugins in 2019?

Tags: neovim

I've been using Vim with vim-plug, yiang-miao/auto-pairs and youcompleteme for a time now, and I really love it; but a friend recently recommended me NeoVim, and it seems it's more polished since it's community driven.

He also suggested I used it without any plugins, but is the autocomplete function on NeoVim better than normal Vim's? I found Vim's built-in lacking coming from VScode, but I don't want to noticeably slow down NeoVim unnecessarily.

Comment: Please explain why Neovim is community driven and Vim is not.

Comment: I was wrong, I meant their leadership, since I've heard Vim has a single contributor

Answer (score 6):

Actually, one big (huge!) feature of NeoVim and Vim 8 is actually meant for plug-in writers, which is the ability to do [asynchronous communication](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#job_start%28%29) with external jobs.

This is especially useful for plug-ins that communicate with external commands, doing tasks such as completion (YouCompleteMe, Deoplete, plug-ins that communicate with a language server using the LSP protocol) or linting (ALE, etc.)

> He also suggested I used it without any plugins, but is the autocomplete function on NeoVim better than normal Vim's?

Not really. Vim's autocompletion features have been around and haven't been significantly changed in NeoVim or Vim 8.

I imagine your friend's recommendation to use it without plug-ins is so that you can experience the full power of native Vim autocompletion and learn to use its advanced features.

Personally, I don't really use a plug-in to do autocompletion, but I do generate `ctags` for most projects I work on and I use [completion from tags](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#compl-tag), which I find does quite a good job for my needs.

I actually *do* use a [plug-in](https://github.com/ludovicchabant/vim-gutentags) to generate and keep the `ctags` file up to date, though.

In the end, it's up to you to decide how Vim works best for you. If you're happy with your current plug-ins, by all means keep using them in NeoVim! If you would like to see more of what it can do out-of-the-box, then disable the plug-ins to "force" you to learn the native way. And don't forget the two are not mutually exclusive, you can still use native completion even if you're also using a plug-in!

Answer (score 1):

I am a Neovim user and have been using Neoivm for about a year. Neovim is initially a fork of Vim and is actively maintained by a few maintainers.

I think you can not notice an apparent difference as a normal user. After all, Neovim is trying to be compatible with Vim. Neovim does have differences with Vim: different default options, new features, removed features, new architecture, etc. For complete documentation on the differences between Neovim and Vim. Open Neovim and use `:h vim-differences`.

As for plugins, it is a subjective topic. Even if you are minimalist, you may want to install a few plugins to enhance your experience with Neovim. Personally, I use more than 60 plugins and I use vim-plug to control when the plugins should be activated.